# When does spellcasting longer than 1 action provoke an Attack of Opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, opportunity-attack

Assuming they do not cast defensively, when a spellcaster takes longer than 1 action to complete a spell (as is the case with long casting time spells and, more likely to see in combat, [Summon Monster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/), [Summon Nature's Ally](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-natures-ally/), [Antilife Shell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antilife-shell/), etc.) when is an Attack of Opportunity provoked? When they begin casting, during the entire round, when they end casting, when they begin *or* end casting, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provoke an attack of opportunity only once, at the beginning of the spell's casting.

From the section "Actions in Combat" in Chapter 8 of the Core Rulebook, under full round actions:

> You only provoke attacks of opportunity when you begin casting a spell, even though you might continue casting for at least 1 full round.